# How to not display a UI?

Tags: windows, api

MSDN at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-cminvokecommandinfo) states that there is a flag

```
CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI

The system is prevented from displaying user interface elements (for example, error messages) while carrying out a command.
```

However, it also indicates that the structure has

```
nShow

Type: int

A set of SW_ values to pass to the ShowWindow function if the command displays a window or starts an application.
```

which I think contradicts each other as there is no indication I can set the latter parameter to 0 and there is no SW_NOSHOW parameter in the `ShowWindow` documentation.

Is it even possible to suppress that window? If yes - how?

TIA!!

Comment: As the documentation says, nShow is used "if the command displays a window". If you pass `CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI`, then you're telling it "Don't display a window." Therefore, the value of nShow is not used.

Comment: @RaymondChen, are you saying that the `flag` has precedence? Because trying to run `Undelete` i still see that window...

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity about which UI we are talking about here.

There are UI things related to invoking the command (asking for network share password, error message on failure etc.) and `CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` certainly applies here. I don't know how relevant `nShow` is though. The caller does not know which UI might be displayed and it makes zero sense for the callee to allow its error `MessageBox` to be maximized etc. Respecting `SW_HIDE` might end up stuck waiting for the user to interact with a window they can't see.

The other UI is actually the thing that is executed. In the cases where a new process is started we are looking at a `ShellExecuteEx` call. `CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` is passed on as `SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` (same integral value) and MSDN just says "Do not display an error message box if an error occurs" for this flag. Here however, `nShow` is relevant and can trickle all the way down to `CreateProcess`.

This is how I personally deal with this situation:

- Set `CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` if you are going to display your own error UI in case of failures or if you are running in a silent/automated mode of execution.
- Only set `nShow` to something other than `SW_SHOW` when you control the action being executed. For example, you know cmd.exe is getting called and you need to hide the console window with `SW_HIDE`.

It is important to remember that `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO` is parsed by the default `IContextMenu` shell32 implementations for various shell objects (files, control panel etc.) and by 3rd-party context menu handlers. You cannot assume that they are going to respect your wishes.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to recover some file/folder from RecycleBin. Everything succeeds, but even though I set `CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` the `copy window` from the explorer is still shows up. How do I turn this off? Keep that flag and use `SW_HIDE`?

Comment: I doubt the transfer dialog respects nShow. How are you invoking the command? Are you a shell extension inside Explorer.exe or do you invoke on a IContextMenu you retrieved yourself?

Comment: @Andres, its the latter.

Comment: I suppose you can try to set hwnd to NULL or to a hidden window but I don't have much hope. Or drop the IContextMenu idea and perform the move operation yourself.